# TransactionFlowAttribute error with WCF Service

Tags: wcf, transactions, wshttpbinding

I have a WCF service that I have configured on my local dev environment and run through IIS using a self signed certificate so I can support SSL and transactions using a wsHttpBinding.

Everything works fine on my local Win7 machine running IIS 7.5.

I am deploying my services app to a Win2008 R2 server running IIS 7.5.

The app pool is configured for .NET 4.0 integrated.

When I run the build and deploy to my Dev server one of the services keeps throwing an InvalidOperation exception that states that the 'WebHttpBinding' my service is using doesn't have the transactionflowattribute set on it.

Here are the only 2 bindings I have configured in my web.config:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRetrieval" closeTimeout="infinite" openTimeout="infinite" receiveTimeout="infinite" sendTimeout="infinite" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding" transactionFlow="true">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Why does the error say that the configured WebHttpBinding doesn't have the attribute set? I don't even have that type of binding specified in the config.

I have another service that also uses the wsHttpBinding I have declared here and that one works fine. So at this point I am pretty much stuck as to why one of them works and the other is throwing the error.

I do have the services tagged as transaction mandatory, and I have everything setup to account for that.

Anyone have any ideas why one of my services is borking and the other is fine?